# SAXException: bad envelope tag

Tags: html, soap, tags, envelope

I'm trying to connect to a webservice https protected through a webservice client.  Eclipse generated a stub based webservice client and looks nice to me.  The problem comes when I try to call a method from the webservice:

```
String a = (String)webservice.userProfileServices(xml);
```

I'm also using the following SOAP headers:

```
esgGatewayPort = (new EsgGatewayLocator()).getesgGatewayPort();

//setting the authentication header
PrefixedQName name = new PrefixedQName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext","Security","wsse");
System.out.println("Setting headers for authentication");
org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement sh = new org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement(name);
SOAPElement sub;

try {

      String clntUserName="myUser";
      String clntPassword="myPassword";
      sub = sh.addChildElement("UsernameToken");
      SOAPElement element = sub.addChildElement("Username");
      element.addTextNode(clntUserName);
      element = sub.addChildElement("Password");
      element.addTextNode(clntPassword);
      ((org.apache.axis.client.Stub) esgGatewayPort).setHeader(sh);

} catch (SOAPException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();

}
```

I receive the following:

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad envelope tag:  HTML
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad envelope tag:  HTML
    at org.apache.axis.message.EnvelopeBuilder.startElement(EnvelopeBuilder.java:71)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1048)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicXMLReader.parse(WebLogicXMLReader.java:133)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader.parse(RegistryXMLReader.java:153)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:796)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
```

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: What does your Soap Header (sh) look like when you call  .setHeader ?   This is not a valid header.

Comment: This is my header code:
esgGatewayPort = (new sgGatewayLocator()).getesgGatewayPort();

Comment: PrefixedQName name = new PrefixedQName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext","Security","wsse");
SOAPHeaderElement sh = new SOAPHeaderElement(name);

Comment: SOAPElement sub;
try {String clntUserName="u";
String clntPassword="p";

Comment: sub = sh.addChildElement("UsernameToken");
SOAPElement element = sub.addChildElement("Username");
element.addTextNode(clntUserName);
element = sub.addChildElement("Password");
element.addTextNode(clntPassword);
((org.apache.axis.client.Stub) esgGatewayPort).setHeader(sh);

Comment: After the setHeader looks to have the username and password.  What the server is responding is HTML code :-(

Comment: SOLVED!!!
Well, Due Eclipse connects to Weblogic and creates the stubs, It defined an endpoint which was http.  I just pointed out to https, got rid of the port and the ending ?WSDL.

Answer (score 6):

**Wrong format of the endpoint**

Ex: http://localhost:8080/YourService/

Ex: http://localhost:8080/YourService?wsdl

**Correct endpoint format to set the constructor**

Ex: http://localhost:8080/YourService

Comment: It was a plaseure, Kishore

Comment: May I know, why we need to call the service without "?wsdl" in WebSphere and with "?wsdl" in other servers ?

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the problem in WAS (WebSphere Application Server), following http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK54518. Applying the appropriate Fix Pack for your version of WAS resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you are trying to bind to a https service using http. I had this problem when eclipse generated the stubs for me from a wsdl that was hosted on a https server.

Edit the generated files by eclipse that points to the server URL and it should connect correctly.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it got resolved after removing "/" from end of the URL in Axis (not Axis2)

The URL which I was using `http://localhost:7000/myWS/`
After changing it to `http://localhost:7000/myWS` worked fine!

Exception:
`Main: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad envelope tag:  table
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:701)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)`

Answer (score 0):

Main: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad envelope tag:  script
In our case error "Bad envelope tag:  script" occurred because of user id got locked