# Eclipse - Creation of Web service error

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

While creating a web service in eclipse kepler , i'm getting this error.

```
IWAB0489E Error when deploying Web service to Axis runtime axis-admin failed 
with  {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException      
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad envelope tag:  HTML
```

My Configuration is

**Web service type :** Bottom up java bean web service

**Server Runtime:** Tomcat v7.0 server.

**Web Service Runtime:** Apache Axis.

How to solve this error?

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272264/eclipse-juno-iwab0489e-error-when-deploying-web-service-to-axis-runtime

Comment: @Hirak Yeah,I've checked that post.It was about "Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL)"

Comment: What about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662972/saxexception-bad-envelope-tag

Comment: Is there any exception on your tomcat server itself?

Comment: @Sanjeev No exceptions are there in  my tomcat server console.